# Executor Memory: Used memory vs Total available memory for storage of data like RDD partitions cached in memory

Tags: apache-spark

I have question on what exactly the  Executors->Storage Memory column indicate on Spark UI.

Executor Memory = 8GB

No of Executors = 17

Spark is running on Mesos Cluster

For individual executors, it is shown 9GB / 5GB

Under Storage memory
Under Summary, it is shown 164.3 GB / 86.8 GB

Why the Used memory is greater than 8GB? If 5GB is available, isn't used memory should be less than 3GB? What exactly used memory includes?

Thanks

Comment: What environment are you running spark?  Is it on EMR with yarn? stand alone?  In some cases spark allocates extra memory for various reasons.

Comment: It is on Mesos cluster.